# Opensource ESB vs Apache ServiceMix vs Spring Integration?

Tags: spring-integration, esb, apache-servicemix

I am new to the enterprise integration area.

We have a requirement to develop a solution where multiple OSS (operations support systems) should talk to multiple EMS (element management systems) and network devices (Different transports and protocols has to be supported), solution should be such that, that it should run in Weblogic.

### Queries

- Which will be the best fit for this situation ESB/Apache ServiceMix/Spring Integration?
- If we use opensource ESBs ( like WSo2 and Talend ESBs) I think we need to maintain two servers ESB server and Weblogic server and ESB/Weblogic integration will be an issue?
- Apache [servicemix](/questions/tagged/servicemix)  or Spring Integration be deployed/run inside Weblogic?
- Whether Apache ServiceMix is supported now, as I could see most updates are happening in [fuse](/questions/tagged/fuse) ESB only?

Comment: Servicemix itself is a ESB, it can be work standalone or can be deployed in any container

Answer (score 5):

You need to analyze your scenario and then decide. If you need only transformation or alongside with a simple routing  you can use some frameworks like smooks, camel etc.

You need to transform and still a lot of system involved where you need those transformed messages then you could use an ESB.

Then comes selecting the ESB product is also based on you application eco system. All products are amazing and each fits the better than the other in their own application eco system.

First you need to know a few things on Camel / Fuse ESB / Service Mix

All the above revolve around the same, each of them are projects where camel integration framework is the coding De fact o

1.Camel -- Integration framework and the De fact o coding way(sophisticated in its own way and much flexible)

2.Service Mix -- Container for deploying the your integration code. (Camel integration code)

3.Fuse ESB -- Enterprise Feather on the hat of Service Mix where it provides a Studio for coding , a list of components and wrappers like clustering and other facilities around service service mix

.

I would like you to also consider Mule ESB which could also and it will be a good contender in your list.

Some answers for your questions
1.You can deploy Camel code or the spring integration code into the what so ever container (all in the hands Maven and jar management thing you need to do....)

2.Service mix is a Apache license and is complete open source and if you need some support I suggest you to choose the FUSE ESB which is not part of JBoss family and powered by RedHat

Please follow this link below for more detailed discussion from other stackoverflow.com users
use the below for your analysis

[Apache Camel and other ESB products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792519/apache-camel-and-other-esb-products)

[What is an ESB and what is it good for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597397/what-is-an-esb-and-what-is-it-good-for)

[Messaging, Queues and ESB's - I know where I want to be but not how to get there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390740/messaging-queues-and-esbs-i-know-where-i-want-to-be-but-not-how-to-get-there)

[JMS and ESB - how they are related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322675/jms-and-esb-how-they-are-related)

Comment: Great Naveen, I will have a look on the links provided by you.