# Silverlight WebClient concurrency limits?

Tags: silverlight, webclient

I am aware that a WebClient instance can only support a single asynchronous request at any one time, therefore in order to perform concurrent requests you need to create multiple WebClient instances. However, is there a limit to the number of WebClients I could, or should create?

For example, if I need to download 100 files, can I just create 100 WebClients? will Silverlight manage this with some sensible concurrency limits? or is that my job? Or do I need to create my own queue mechanism for requests?

Also, what about Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are connection to a single host (server) the connection limit imposed by the browser is 2 outgoing connections at a time. The same limit would be there in Windows Phone but i am not sure. Therefore more than 2 requests made either from the same webclient or different would get queued. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229011/aynchronous-web-server-calls-in-silverlight-and-maximum-http-connections)