# WCF service event thrown when method not called

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, asynchronous

I couldn't find info on this anywhere. Basically, the web service function I'm calling (basic http binding, only operationcontract, no cross domain stuff) is throwing its completed event even though the breakpoints inside the function are never hit. The function is called x times, and I hit the breakpoints up until the 3rd attempt at calling. Then, it just skips straight to the event completed.

I included a flag that tells me what iteration of the function threw the event completed, so I know the event belongs to the function attempt that is never hit.

I tried recalling the function in its event completed if it never was actually completed, but this has lead to a plethora of random async calls at random points in time. My output's a mess. =) It actually works like 1 in 10 times, weirdly enough.

Any ideas on what's causing this?

P.S.: this is Silverlight 4 -> WCF Service in C#.

Comment: Can we see some code on how you are calling the service?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used WCF in Silverlight before, but I've heard references to how you are [limited to two outstanding asynchronous calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229011/aynchronous-web-server-calls-in-silverlight-and-maximum-http-connections). You have to complete the first two before starting a third.

Are the `EventArgs` passed into your handler derived from `AsyncCompletedEventArgs`? If so, check the Error property to see if it gives you any clues.